# In PHP, is it possible to add an interface to a class without changing the code of the class itself?

Tags: php

Can I add an interface ... e.g.

```
interface MyInterface {
    //...
}
```

to a class

```
class MyClass {
    //...
}
```

without rewriting the class to be:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    //...
}
```

in Php 5.3+

Comment: Can I drive a car without a car? [This smells like you are asking the wrong question btw](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Ha ha ha - yes - you are probably right... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you can't... although I do agree with PeeHaa, it seems like you're not exactly asking the right question.